# Highcharts options overwriting issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to integrate few charts (highcharts) in my HTML page, but I have little knowledge of Javascript. I am using multiple types of charts in my page displayed separately on click event of different elements.
The problem I am facing is after rendering one chart, some of its options are applied to remaining charts. The issue can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/manojvij73/pen/xxVqgyK). Here if bar chart is rendered separately, all options like color etc. are rendered as expected. But if bullet chart is opened first and then we open bar chart, things get messed. Bars turn black from its original blue color. Thanks in advance!

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
        inverted: false,
        marginLeft: 0,
        type: 'line'
    }
});
```

Comment: Move your setOptions objects properties in the chart that you want to be affected.

Comment: I think that some of those options doesn't make sense at all, like `title.text` in the setOptions config and inside each config are confused. I think that the best approach will be skip the `setOptions` config.

Comment: @alvarofvr:You are right! setOptions sets properties globally. I moved individual properties inside the chart settings and the issue is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I answered your question! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

`Highcharts.setOptions` is used for set chart object properties globally, you should move individual properties inside `Highcharts.chart` object properties.

In this case an example is moving global options:

```
// Affect all charts and you need to override it
Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
        inverted: false,
        marginLeft: 0,
        type: 'line'
    }
});
```

to chart options:

```
// Affect only this chart and/or override global properties
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
    chart: {
        inverted: false,
        marginLeft: 0,
        type: 'line'
    }
});
```